# Как найти в теме wordpress функцию вывода заголовка h1

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

Помогите плиз с задачей, а то прям никак. Пытаюсь сделать произвольный заголовок H1 для категорий WordPress/Woocommerce. Закинул в archive-product.php код:

```
<?php
if (!empty(get_queried_object()->term_id)) {
    $id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        $taxomony = get_queried_object()->taxonomy;
}               
$title =  get_term_meta($id , 'title', 1 ); // Теперь в этой переменной h1 заголовок
    if ($title) {
        echo $title;
    } elseif ($taxomony == 'product_cat' & !$title) {
       echo woocommerce_page_title(); //Для Woocommerce
    } else {
           echo 'Здесь функция вывода, в разных шаблонах она разная, посмотрите, как выводится у вас и вставьте сюда стандартную функцию или переменную для вывода заголовка';
}
?>
```

Вот тут задача, не знаю где найти функцию вывода заголовка h1 в теме wordpress, чтобы ее подставить. Помогите плиз кто может

---

вот код archive-product.php:

```
    <?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.4.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header( 'shop' );

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

?>
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>
</header>
<?php
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
             *
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
} else {
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
     *
     * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );

get_footer( 'shop' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для woocommerce

Если тема поддерживает woocommerce

```
function setup_woocommerce_support(){
  add_theme_support('woocommerce');
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_woocommerce_support' );
```

То искать нужно в папке "активная_тема/woocommerce/archive-product.php"

```
<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Также можно наложить фильтр на woocommerce_page_title()

```
// define the woocommerce_page_title callback 
function filter_woocommerce_page_title( $page_title ) { 
            // make filter magic happen here... 
            return $page_title; 
}; 
                 
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'filter_woocommerce_page_title', 10, 1 );
```

http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_page_title/

2. Для wordpress искать согласно иерархии шаблона https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies

Comment: Спасибо Валерий за ответ, но я тут не вижу вывода, возможно я что то не понимаю, но тема wocommerce поддерживает, а саму функцию в archive-product.php не вижу, вот код:

Comment: @Alex_webmaster ориентируйтесь на родной шаблов в плагине woocommerce. wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php . В вашем файле отсутствует блок с заголовком